# In Capistrano, how to create a .rvmrc file in the /current folder?

Tags: ubuntu, capistrano

During my deploy, I want to create a .rvmrc file in the /current folder during a capistrano deployment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tasks to a Capistrano deploy using syntax shown below :

```
task :gitinstall do
   run "apt-get update"
   run "apt-get -y install git-core"
end
before "deploy:update", :gitinstall
```

This example has each machine install git before running the deploy. All you have to do is modify this to wget the file in question or do a bash echo.

Comment: thanks, but why 'bash echo', I need a command to create a file on the fly and add something like ruby-version@gemset_name no?

Comment: If you need to add that in the file you can do : echo "ruby-version@gemset_name no" >> ~/.rvmrc

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here as reference. Should work with newer versions of rbenv or rvm.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Sets the ruby version'
  task :set_ruby_version do
    put "2.0.0-p0", "#{latest_release}/.ruby-version"
  end
end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:set_ruby_version'
```

or, if you're using capistrano/bundler, you need this hook instead:

```
before 'bundle:install', 'deploy:set_ruby_version'
```